# Can I draw the area of an integral with Oxyplot?

Tags: c#, integral, oxyplot, mathnet-numerics

Is it possible to draw the area of a certain integral in Oxyplot?

With the `MathNet.Numerics` library it is possible to calculate these integrals but I am wondering if I am able to draw it in my plot?

Comment: Hi there.  Can you include an example plot of what you need as you get from MathNet.Numerics, as well as the code that got you that example?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer,
this code gives me the area of the integral (`-x²+50`):
`Integrate.OnClosedInterval(x => -1 * (x * x) + 50, 0, 5)`

and i want it to look like this:http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/test08jlxdp3k4.png

Comment: Is that plot image drawn by the `Integrate.OnClosedInterval()` call?

Comment: No, it's just a number.

Comment: I see what you're saying now. MathNet.Numerics does the integral and you want it plotted by Oxyplot.  I don't know either of those libraries.  Hopefully someone who does sees your question.  Good luck.

Comment: Yes, that is the issue.

Comment: Have you figured out how to plot lambdas like `x => -1 * (x * x) + 50, 0, 5)` without the area underneath?

Comment: Yes, i know how to plot `-x²+50` with oxyplot. But i still don't know how to draw a certain integral...

Comment: Can you show me that choose please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am no expert in the matter, but I may have found something helpfull for you... 
Take a look at `AreaSeries`. I think this is what you need.

Example:

```
        var model = new PlotModel { Title = "AreaSeries" };

        var series = new AreaSeries { Title = "integral" };
        for (double x = -10; x <= 10; x++)
        {
            series.Points.Add(new DataPoint(x, (-1 * (x * x) + 50)));
        }

        model.Series.Add(series);
```

Then you set the model to your `PlotView.Model` and you should see a plot similar at what you posted in the comments above.

I hope this works for you.

----- EDIT (because of comment in the answer) -----

It turns out that you actually can do what you asked in the comments. You just need to fill `AreaSeries.Points2` with the points you want to restrict your Area. For example, in my previous sample add inside the `for` the following line

```
series.Points2.Add(new DataPoint(x, x));
```

Then you will have the area defined by two lines: `y = -x^2 + 50` and `y = x`. You can even set the second line transparent.

Complete Example:

```
        var model = new PlotModel { Title = "AreaSeries" };

        var series = new AreaSeries { Title = "series" };
        for (double x = -10; x <= 10; x++)
        {
            series.Points.Add(new DataPoint(x, (-1 * (x * x) + 50)));
            series.Points2.Add(new DataPoint(x, x));
        }
        series.Color2 = OxyColors.Transparent;

        model.Series.Add(series);

        plotView.Model = model;
```

Now you just have to add the formulas that you need, and it should show a similar graph to the one you put in your comment.

Comment: Although it does not work for all kinds of functions: http://www.pic-upload.de/view-28746614/integral.png.html

Comment: That's right. That last graph is a little more complicated... Can you put the equation of the curve? I will think about it and see if I can come with any trick

Comment: I just updated the answer. Take a look. It turns out to be quite simple. Just add the second series to "series.Points2" and you are ready to go!